# Use php and sql to make an action url per item id

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I am trying to make page in php/html that will display a "product's details." I have it displaying the icon and the link to the "details page," but it will not display ONLY one item on the "details page." Currently, the product's page (where the icon and the link are) will link to the "details page" just fine. However, when the page loads it loads every item in the sql database that has an 'ID.' I expected it to only take the item's id and display the page related to that item, however I received a cluster of them all... The code I have is what follows. I am currently trying to learn PHP so please if I make an error, a really bad one like something that isn't efficient. Please post the more efficient way of doing it. I am learning it the way I was taught at school.

```
        <?php
//This page display a topic
include('admin/variable.php');
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select c.id, c.name, c.description, c.price, c.quantity, c.itemID, c.imgName, c.position, (select count(t.id) from topics as t where t.parent=c.id and t.id2=1) as topics, (select count(t2.id) from topics as t2 where t2.parent=c.id and t2.id2!=1) as replies from categories as c group by c.id order by c.position asc'));
if($dn1['id']>0)
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title><?php echo htmlentities($dn1['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> - <?php echo htmlentities($dn1['itemID'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> - KB Computers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Forum" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
<?php

?>
<h1><?php echo $dn1['name']; ?></h1>
<?php

$dn2 = mysql_query('select c.id, c.name, c.description, c.price, c.quantity, c.itemID, c.imgName, c.position, c.position, (select count(t.id) from topics as t where c.parent=c.id and t.id2=1) as topics, (select count(t2.id) from topics as t2 where t2.parent=c.id and t2.id2!=1) as replies from categories as c group by c.id WHERE c.id = ' . $id .' order by c.position asc');

 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 while($dnn2 = mysql_fetch_array($dn2))  //This is line 30!
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

{
    $parent = $dnn2['parent'];
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    if($_GET['id'] == $parent){ 

?>
<div id="thing">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $dnn2['imgName']; ?></th>
        </tr>
        <br />
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $dnn2['price']; ?></th>
        </tr>
        <br />
        <tr>
            <th> <?php echo $dnn2['description']; ?></th>
        </tr>
        <br />
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $dnn2['itemID']; ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SEESION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] == $admin){?><div class="edit"><a href="edit_product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&id2=<?php echo $dnn2['itemID']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/edic.png" alt="Edit" /></a></div>

        <?php } ?>

    </table></div>
<?php
}else{echo 'The parent and id values are not the same.';}
}}
?>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>This topic doesn\'t exisc.</h2>';
}
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>The ID of this topic is not defined.</h2>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you need a clause like `WHERE c.id = ' . $id '...` in your query.

Comment: Where would i put that? I'm learning more PHP than sql.

Comment: It's hard to tell without an explanation of your table structure, but probably right after `from categories`. BTW, your `$dn1` and `$dn2` queries are almost identical. Why do you do the same query twice?

Comment: I am getting the following error

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .... on line 30

where i have the .... its the directory.

I have also bolded line 30 from the above sections of code.

Comment: That means the query is getting an error. You need to check whether `mysql_query()` is succeeding, and print `mysql_error()` when it fails to see the error message.

Comment: @Barmar See my answer below if you want to see what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//This page display a topic
include('admin/variable.php');
include('home.php');

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$dn1 = mysql_query('select 
     c.id, 
     c.name, 
     c.description, 
     c.price, 
     c.quantity, 
     c.itemID, 
     c.imgName, 
     c.parent, 
     c.position, 
(select count(c.id) from categories as c where c.parent=c.id) as categories, (select count(c.id) from categories as c where c.parent=c.id and c.id!=0) as replies from categories as c group by c.id order by c.position asc');
if($dn1 === false){
        die(mysql_error());
    }
while($dnn1 = mysql_fetch_array($dn1))
{
$parent = $dnn1['parent'];
  if($_GET['id'] == $parent){ 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="require/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
    <title><?php echo htmlentities($dnn1['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> - <?php echo htmlentities($dnn1['itemID'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> - KB Computers</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="Content">
<div style="background:white; height:800px;">

<div id="shopNav">
<ul>
    <li class="end"><a href="">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Catagories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">New Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
            <li class="end2"><a href="">Checkout</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

<div id="thing">
<table><h1><?php echo $dnn1['name']; ?></h1>
<tr>
 <th><?php echo '<img src="image/' . $dnn1['imgName'].'" alt="' . $dnn1['imgName']. '" width="128" height="128"'; ?></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><?php echo $dnn1['price']; ?></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="tableDesc"> <?php echo $dnn1['description']; ?></th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $dnn1['itemID']; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_SEESION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] == $admin){?>
        <tr>
        <a href="edit_product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&id2=<?php echo $dnn1['itemID']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/edic.png" alt="Edit" /></a>>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <th> </th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php include("require/rightBar.html"); ?></div><?php include("require/footer.html"); 
}
}
}else{echo 'That product doesnt exist!';}
?>

    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: You got rid of all the database code? That's a good way to stop those pesky mysql errors. :)

Comment: I messed up, I actually have the Sql stuff in there. I just condensed it. Instead of doing the same thing twice I am just doing it once. For a lot of this. I must say though, thank you so much for all your help @Barmar